# Pentaho Report Designer Concatenate + Date formating

Tags: pentaho, report-designer

Currently I have this formula:

```
=CONCATENATE([ResourceMesssageFormatExpression3];" ";DAY(NOW());"/";MONTH(NOW());"/";YEAR(NOW());" ";HOUR(NOW());":";MINUTE(NOW()))
```

The resource message format expression is a resource label that gets translated to
' Generated on: ' and then it should show the date as followed: 06/05/2015 08:36

Day/Month/Year Hour:Minutes 
Is does that good only my leading zeros are gone. It shows `6/5/2015 8:36` instead of: `06/05/2015 08:36`

Any advice on how I can show my leading zeros?

Comment: Found a solution: =CONCATENATE([ResourceMesssageFormatExpression3];" ";MESSAGE("{0,date,dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm}";NOW()))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
=CONCATENATE([ResourceMesssageFormatExpression3];" ";MESSAGE("{0,date,dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm}";NOW()))
```